# Tablet Break Point Fails in Responsive CSS Fluid Grid Design

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, dreamweaver, fluid-layout

Created a responsive site in Dreamweaver CS6 using the Fluid Grid system. All break points initially worked fine, and I had 3 separate layouts for desktop, tablet, and mobile; with different resolutions, each Fluid Grid Layout Div Tag would rearrange on the page into different columns. Every div on the page is set up with `width: __%;` in the CSS so that they expand and contract with the browser size.

Everything is responsive on the page and works correctly; however, somewhere during development I lost the **Tablet** break point, in a sense. When the browser reaches the `768px` width which should break the page into the Tablet layout, it instead jumps straight to the mobile formatting, which should not happen until `480px`.

In Dreamweaver, I can view the formatting I have set for the Tablet layout, in Design mode it will show me the correct layout of columns of DIVs and content; however, once I place DW in **Live** mode, or preview in a browser, it no longer has the Tablet functionality, just Desktop and Mobile formatting.

I will post the CSS code for the `@media` queries and the subsequent `.gridContainer` code - trying to see if a solution could be found without having to post the entire CSS code, as there's quite alot. Please let me know if I need to edit my question and include more code - perhaps the truncated code of a few DIVs and their responsive values for each layout? I'd be happy to post any more information if it will help resolve this issue.

*Thank you in advance for any support or advice!*

**CSS:**

```
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer:before, .container:after {
    display:table;
    content:"";
    zoom:1 /* ie fix */;
}

.gridContainer:after {
    clear:both;
}

.gridContainer {
    width: 96%;
    padding-left: 1.5%;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
    border:1px solid #00133e;
    background: #004aa1;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer:before, .container:after {
    display:table;
    content:"";
    zoom:1 /* ie fix */;
}

.gridContainer:after {
    clear:both;
}

.gridContainer {
    width: 96%;
    padding-left: 1.5%;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

.gridContainer:before, .container:after {
    display:table;
    content:"";
    zoom:1 /* ie fix */;
}

.gridContainer:after {
    clear:both;
}

.gridContainer {
    width: 96%;
    padding-left: 1.5%;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Near the end of my mobile layout CSS style code, there was an extra curly brace. Removed the brace, responsiveness returns.

Very simple solution; thanks to @MrRO for pointing me in the right direction to look!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, this is copy paste of actual code. In the given CSS, I believe you have have missed one curly braces, which was suppose to close the style for `<480` width devices.

```
background: #004aa1;
} <-- Here one more "}" needed

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer:before, .container:after {
```

Comment: Good catch - but this spot should not have a second curly brace, as the CSS code starts without any `@media` code. The mobile version is default, and then it starts pushing into the Tablet mode at `481px`.